# How to set complex/nested state's property on Reducer using ImmutableJS?

Tags: typescript, redux, immutability, immutable.js

Currently I have following object structure defined as **initial state of the STORE**

```
{
  counter: 0,
  messages: {
    newMessages: 25,
    inbox: 100
  }
}
```

and here i'm using **immutableJS**, and in my **reducer** if I want to modify the state i'll implement something like this:

```
function myReducer(state: Map<string, any>, action): Map<string, any> {
  switch (action.type) {
    case COUNTER_INCREMENT:
      return state.set('counter', state.get('counter') + 1);
    case INBOX_INCREMENT:
      return state.set(xxxx, yyyy + 1);
  }
  return state;
}
```

when modifying simple property like `counter` we can just use simple

```
state.set('counter', state.get('counter') + 1)
```

but what if we want to modify **complex/nested property** like `messages.inbox`? what should `xxxx` and `yyyy` value be?

Answer (score 2):

Immutable provides a `setIn` command by which you provide a path of nesting and the value so set that path to.

From the [Immutable docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/):

```
const { fromJS } = require('immutable')
const nested = fromJS({ a: { b: { c: [ 3, 4, 5 ] } } })

const nested2 = nested.mergeDeep({ a: { b: { d: 6 } } })
// Map { a: Map { b: Map { c: List [ 3, 4, 5 ], d: 6 } } }

console.log(nested2.getIn([ 'a', 'b', 'd' ])) // 6

const nested3 = nested2.updateIn([ 'a', 'b', 'd' ], value => value + 1)
console.log(nested3);
// Map { a: Map { b: Map { c: List [ 3, 4, 5 ], d: 7 } } }

const nested4 = nested3.updateIn([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], list => list.push(6))
// Map { a: Map { b: Map { c: List [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ], d: 7 } } }
```

No example is provided for `setIn` directly, but I imagine the semantics are similar. The docs for it can be found [here](https://facebook.github.io/setIn).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a new value for `messages.inbox`, you would use [`setIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn):

```
return state.setIn(['messages', 'inbox'], 101)
```

If you want to set a new value for `messages.inbox` based on it's current value, you would use [`updateIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn):

```
return state.updateIn(['messages', 'inbox'], inbox => inbox + 1
```